# ¿Es posible crear y leer sesiones desde PHP mediante ajax con React JS?

Tags: php, ajax, axios

Soy nuevo en *React* y me gustaría saber como crear una sesión de *PHP* desde *Ajax*, tampoco he logrado crear una cookie con la función `setcookie()` de *PHP*.

¿Existe la posibilidad de crear sesiones de PHP `session_start()` desde *Ajax* (`fetch`/[axios](/questions/tagged/axios))?

He realizado las peticiones desde *Ajax* y en el archivo *PHP* cuando creo la sesión `$_SESSION['nueva_session']` no la registra en el browser y tampoco la reconoce en una futura petición *Ajax*.

### Edit:

Luego de varias pruebas, logré hacerlo con el proyecto compilado.

Cuando hago la petición desde *React* con `127.0.0.1:3000` no me crea la sesión, cuando lo hago desde 127.0.0.1 con el proyecto ya compilado si la crea.

> Nota: La petición *Ajax* siempre fue a `127.0.0.1/login.php`

Comment: Y por qué desde react?, Tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato, lee [ask]

Comment: Porque estoy empezando un nuevo proyecto donde se usa react de frontend y php de backend

Comment: Yo te recomiendo revisar la naturaleza de uso de react no veo que tiene que ver con sesiones, eso lo creas desde PHP enviando las credenciales desde una petición Ajax

Comment: He realizado las peticiones desde ajax y en el archivo php cuando creo la sesion $_SESSION['nueva_session'] no la registra en el browser y tampoco la reconoce en una futura peticion ajax.

Comment: Insisto entonces aquí react no tiene nada que ver y tú pregunta debe girar entorno a la petición Ajax eje realizas y el fallo en persistir la sesión, edita y agrega esto último que me dices en los comentarios

Comment: para registrar la sesión  en el navegador necesitas hacer uso de cookies. Tal como dice @BetaM tu duda no tiene mucho que ver con react.

Comment: React lo uso solo para el frontend solo recalco que lo uso. El problema sería en los datos que llegan/devuelve PHP mediante ajax... @hawks entiendo que debo utilizar las cookies, pero al llamar al script mediante ajax no se crean dichas cookies...

Comment: Realizando otras pruebas, compile el proyecto y así si la crea... ¿Podría ser el puerto 3000 que no hace crear la sesion al servidor apache? Me parece extraño, ya que la llamada ajax va al apache directamente.

Comment: Si tu servidor y tu frontend estan en distintos dominios o puertos no se enviarán las cookies. Las cookies siempre se envian si el frontend y backend tienen el mismo dominio. Puedes mirar como usar cors y como enviar cookies con ajax